# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "----' does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm using SQlite for development environment and Postgre for Production.

At the development everything works nicely. But when I try to reset and to migrate the production Database I received the following message:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "priceranges" does not exist
...
FOREIGN KEY ("pricerange_id")
REFERENCES "priceranges" ("id")
```

My venue model:

```
belongs_to :pricerange, :class_name => "PriceRange"
```

My pricerange migration:

```
class CreatePriceRanges< ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
   create_table :price_ranges do |t|
    t.string :price_description
    t.timestamps
   end
  end
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The table name you are creating in your migration is `price_ranges`, not `priceranges`.  Unless you are overriding the table name in the `PriceRange` model, your `pricerange` association on `Venue` will look for a foreign key named `price_range_id`, not `pricerange_id`.  I would recommend sticking with convention, and making your association:

```
belongs_to :price_range # automatically uses class PriceRange, and foreign key `price_range_id`
```

Comment: I corrected what you said. But when i created my venue model I used pricerange:references, generating the follow code at my migration:

 t.references :pricerange, foreign_key:true  

I changed to price_range, reseted my database, but the message persists and the venue model continuing create pricerange_id. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I can't say, without seeing your code.  I suspect you still have a reference to `pricerange` somewhere in your code or schema.  You might try a global search and replace of `pricerange` to `price_range`, then `rake db:drop db:create db:migrate`.